# How to add Resources to a control with XAML, similar to ctrl.Resources.Add()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently I can add resources to a control with something similar to the following:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Resources.Add("item", currentItem);
```

I'd like to do this with XAML. I've tried something like

```
<Button Content="Timers Overview"   Name="btnTimerOverview">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- not sure what to add here, or if this is even correct -->               
            <!-- I'd like to add something like a <string, string> mapping -->               
            <!-- like name="items" value="I am the current item."  --> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

but I haven't gotten any further than this. Is there a way to do this in XAML?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using Resources?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to associate a value with the control that can be mapped to another configuration file that is external to the system. When the control is being loaded I can read this value stored as a resource and get a configuration from the external config based on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonResources.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
        >
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Timers Overview"   Name="btnTimerOverview">
            <Button.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- not sure what to add here, or if this is even correct -->
                    <!-- I'd like to add something like a <string, string> mapping -->
                    <!-- like name="items" value="I am the current item."  -->
                    <system:String x:Key="item1">Item 1</system:String>
                    <system:String x:Key="item2">Item 2</system:String>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That looks like what would be ideal, but the type system:String is not found.

Comment: You must add namespace : xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define a ResourceDictionary under Button.Resources

You can just add any kind of Resource like this:

```
<Button Content="Timers Overview"   Name="btnTimerOverview">
    <Button.Resources>
        <!--resources need a key -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="fontBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <!--But styles may be key-less if they are meant to be "implicit",
            meaning they will apply to any element matching the TargetType.
            In this case, every TextBlock contained in this Button 
            will have its Foreground set to "Blue" -->
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource fontBrush}" />
        </Style>
        <!-- ... -->
        <sys:String x:Key="myString">That is a string in resources</sys:String> 
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

With `sys` being mapped as:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Now, I think I understand you want that string to be loaded from some application Settings/Configuration: it is not constant.

For that, it's a bit trickier:
Either you have the string available statically, and then you can do:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:MyStaticConfigClass.TheStaticStringIWant}" />
```

Or it's in a non static object, and you will need to use `Binding` and an `IValueConverter` with the name of the resource as `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want to associate e.g. an arbitrary string value with the control, rather than a style or brush.

Comment: So just add a string with a key. I will add the string example.